# Using Compiled Linq To SQL with ExecuteMethodCall

Tags: sql, linq

Our very large code base has hundreds of calls to ExecuteMethodCall, following this pattern:

```
    [Function(Name = "dbo.storedproc")]
    public ISingleResult<UserData> GetUserData(
        [Parameter(Name = "UserId", DbType = "BigInt")] long? userId)
    {
        IExecuteResult result = ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod())), userId);
        return ((ISingleResult<UserData>)(result.ReturnValue));
    }
```

However, this turns out to give huge performance problems (well known problem with Linq To SQL). So I am looking at converting at least some of this code to Compiled Linq To Sql.

I found examples of Compiled Linq To Sql, but none of them involve ExecuteMethodCall. Instead, they all compile a Linq query (from ... where ... select).

I would be grateful if someone could give me an example of the above code (using ExecuteMethodCall) converted to Compiled Linq To SQL.

Comment: Did you see this post on microsoft blog?[Linq to SQL Stored Procedures - Guy Burstein's Blog](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.microsoft.co.il%2Fblogs%2Fbursteg%2Farchive%2F2007%2F10%2F05%2Flinq-to-sql-stored-procedures.aspx&ei=jJKgULCXO9KU0QX9q4EQ&usg=AFQjCNEr-IG2GRfwSLPBGPXQvDqQUwASIg&sig2=EGHEXpCmAfS-V3ok9AZzvg&cad=rja) I think it may be useful

Comment: Just read that post. However, it doesn't show how to use ExecuteMethodCall with a compiled linq to sql query.

Comment: Where exactly is the performance problem? Is it `GetCurrentMethod()` that's slowing you down or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

select * from user where userid = userId (argument of the method) ,

SP: exec GetUserData @userId = userId